# a theorem on the dimension of finite algebras over a field (Hartshorne)

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Robin Hartshorne in his Algebraic Geometry, Theorem 1.8A(b), p. 6, says that if $B$ is an integral domain which is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, $k$ a field, and $p$ a prime ideal of $B$, then $ht(p)+\dim B/p = \dim B$. For a proof, he is referencing Matsumura and Atiyah-MacDonald. Even though, i have both books (albeit Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory and not Commutative Algebra), i can not locate this theorem. Any pointers?

Comment: @YACP: Could you please provide once moore the link you had to this nice reference? Actually I had not saved it and I would still like to access it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The desired reference is Corollary 13.9 (page 290) of Eisenbud's "Commutative Algebra with a view towards Algebraic Geometry".

Comment: I am finding Eisenbud's "proof" almost tautaulogic...